# Kubuntu - how to find out what DB is installed

Tags: database, kubuntu, sqlite

I'm newbie in linux, I installed latest kubuntu release. I was told that it already has sqlite on it/ How can I find out is it installed and what version of SQLite is on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the sqlite is installed, running this command in a terminal will give you the version:

```
$ sqlite -version
2.8.17
```

As you can see, on my system it is version 2.8.17. The `$` in the above example is a Unix convention to indicate that the command is run on a terminal (`#` is used to indicate commands run as the `root` user), you should not explicitly type it.

If the above command gives you a "No command found" error, then sqlite is not installed and you can install it by running this command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite
```

Comment: I receive "No command found", but I added to Firefox SQLite Manager, and it works, I creates tables..

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the package manager (adept) to check which packages are installed. (To start adept from the command line use `kdesu adept`).

Failing that, this is an ugly workaround which at least shows major versions:

Create a database, then use the  `file` command on it.

```
$ file file2.db
file2.db: SQLite 2.x database

$ file file3.db
file3.db: SQLite 3.x database
```